# Gunicorn (Python3.4 and 3.3) sends in response only headers without data

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi, gunicorn

I have vm in cloud, python 3.3 (also tried with 3.4 - same result) and Gunicorn 18.
I copy/paste 'hello world' app (app.py):

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = "Hello, World!\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

then run

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app
```

workers started without errors, but when I tried to open it with browser I get only headers with no body:

```
Connection: "close"
Content-Length: "14"
...and so on
```

If I add some custom header I'll get it in response but no response body.
Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not a valid WSGI application for Python 3 for a start. It must return an iterable over byte strings, not native (unicode in python 3) strings. Using iter() is also redundant, return the list directly.

Answer (score 19):

To add to Graham's explanation, replacing

```
return iter([data])
```

with

```
return [bytes(data, 'utf-8')]
```

works for me under Python 3. That solved the same problem when I had it too.

Comment: And, a probably better return value than `[bytes(data, 'utf-8')]` would be `[data.encode('utf-8')]`. I find it more readable.

Comment: This certainly *does* provide an answer to the  question that I had and that brought me here.